# How do I connect to a SQL server database with python?

Tags: python, sql-server, database, database-connection

Im trying to conennect to an sql database that its already created an that its located on a server. How can I connect to this database using python. Ive tried using java but I cant seem to get working either.

Comment: Stack Overflow focuses on *specific* questions, like "How do I use Django's ORM to connect to a SQL server?" (you can find lots of already-asked questions about such topics, eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430091/connecting-django-with-mssql-server).  However, it's not the place to ask "there are five trillion libraries (slight exaggeration) for working with databases in Python: which should I use?"  There are forums and comparison sites elsewhere on the web devoted to answering those questions: SO sticks to helping you once you pick one (and have trouble).

Answer (score 26):

Well depending on what sql database you are using you can pip install pymssql for microsoft sql (mssql), psycopg2 for postgres (psql) or mysqldb for mysql databases
Here are a few examples of using it

Microsoft sql

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server=server, user=user, password=password, database=db)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(MemberID) as count FROM Members WHERE id = 1")
row = cursor.fetchone()

conn.close()

print(row)
```

Postgres

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database=db, user=user, password=password, host=host, port="5432")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(MemberID) as count FROM Members WHERE id = 1')
row = cursor.fetchone()

conn.close()

print(row)
```

mysql

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, db=db)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(MemberID) as count FROM Members WHERE id = 1')
row = cursor.fetchone()

conn.close()

print(row)
```

Comment: Step by step on configuring pymssql for python dev https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pymssql-python-development?view=sql-server-2017 ...and thanks @davidejones