# Connecting Django with MSSQL server

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, django, django-mssql

I'm trying to connect my Django app to SQL Server 2016. I've tried using django-pyodbc but it doesn't support Django 1.11. Instead I installed django-mssql 1.8. When I try to run the application I get this error.

```
TypeError was unhandled by user code
Message: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

At `execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)` in manage.py.

Here is my DATABASES from settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'NAME': 'TEST2',
        'HOST': 'PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'provider': 'SQLOLEDB',
            'use_mars': True,
        },
    }
}
```

I've tried both the default and SQLOLEDB provider but always get the same error. I've also tried with and without user and password set but the error remains the same. I am able to connect to a local MySQL DB just fine.

I'm running Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015, SQL Server Express 2016

Edit:

Here's the output from `pip freeze`:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
Django==1.11
django-mssql==1.8
mysqlclient==1.3.10
packaging==16.8
pyodbc==4.0.16
pyparsing==2.2.0
pytz==2017.2
six==1.10.0
```

Here's my requirements.txt:

```
django==1.11
mysqlclient==1.3.10
django-mssql==1.8
```

Comment: Have you installed mssql via pip?

Comment: Yeah, I installed django-mssql via pip and added to the requirements.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the [django-mssql documentation](https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#dependencies), the latest release only supports Django 1.8, so it won't work with Django 1.11.

You will have to wait until the package supports newer versions of django to upgrade. That is the problem when using Django with non-supported database backends, you depend on the third party packages maintenance, and this one seems to have trouble staying up to date with Django.

Answer (score 5):

Using [**mssql-django**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkjqf.png), we can connect **Django** to **MSSQL(SQL Server)** with **Windows Authentication** and **SQL Server Authentication**. *I use **SQL Server 2019 Express**.

With **Windows Authentication**, to connect **Django** to **MSSQL** using [**mssql-django**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkjqf.png), set the code below to **"settings.py"**. This code below is the example of **Django** and **MSSQL** in **the same Windows Computer(localhost)** and **"ENGINE"** must be **"mssql"** and **"NAME"** is for **Database name "test"** and **"DESKTOP-QVRCPTA"** for **"HOST"** is **Windows Computer Name(Device name)**. *Keep it blank for **"PORT"** because there will be error if setting any port number e.g. **"2244"**, **"9877"** or even **"1433"** which is **the default port number of MSSQL**:

```py
# "settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'mssql',                    # Must be "mssql"
        'NAME':'test',                       # DB name "test"
        'HOST':'DESKTOP-QVRCPTA\SQLEXPRESS', # <server>\<instance>
        'PORT':'',                           # Keep it blank
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

In addition, **"DESKTOP-QVRCPTA"** can be replaced with **"localhost"** and **"USER"** and **"PASSWORD"** can be put with **empty string** and **"PORT"** can be removed as shown below to connect **Django** to **MSSQL** with **Windows Authentication**:

```py
# "settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'mssql',
        'NAME':'test',
        'USER':'',                     # Keep it blank
        'PASSWORD':'',                 # Keep it blank
        'HOST':'localhost\SQLEXPRESS', # "localhost" is also possible
        # 'PORT':'',                   # Can be removed
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

With **SQL Server Authentication**, to connect **Django** to **MSSQL** using [**mssql-django**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkjqf.png), set the code for **Windows Authentication** as shown above with **"USER"** and **"PASSWORD"** to **"settings.py"**. *The difference between the code for **Windows Authentication** and **SQL Server Authentication** is only **"USER"** and **"PASSWORD"**:

```py
# "settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'mssql',  
        'NAME':'test',           
        'USER':'john',                       # Username "john"
        'PASSWORD':'johnpw',                 # Password "johnpw"
        'HOST':'DESKTOP-QVRCPTA\SQLEXPRESS',
        'PORT':'',                           
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

In addition, same as the code for **Windows Authentication**, **"DESKTOP-QVRCPTA"** can be replaced with **"localhost"** and **"PORT"** can be removed as shown below to connect **Django** to **MSSQL** with **SQL Server Authentication**:

```py
# "settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'mssql',
        'NAME':'test',
        'USER':'john',        
        'PASSWORD':'johnpw',
        'HOST':'localhost\SQLEXPRESS', # "localhost" is also possible
        # 'PORT':'',                   # Can be removed   
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

Next, install **the latest package [mssql-django](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django)**:

```
pip install mssql-django
```

Then, make migrations and migrate:

```
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

Then, create superuser:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Now, we could connect **Django** to **MSSQL** with **Windows Authentication** and **SQL Server Authentication**, then create the tables for **"test" database**.

Answer (score 4):

Following official [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#using-a-3rd-party-database-backend) (currently django 3.1)
[django-mssql-backend](https://github.com/ESSolutions/django-mssql-backend) should be used. **Django-MSSQL-backend** django database adapter is a fork of *django-pyodbc-azure* which:

- Supports Django 2.2, 3.0
- Supports Microsoft SQL Server 2008/2008R2, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019
- Compatible with Micosoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server, SQL Server Native Client, and FreeTDS ODBC drivers

Other solutions [django-pyodbc-azure](https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/), [django-sqlserver](https://github.com/denisenkom/django-sqlserver) and [django-mssql](https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#dependencies) as of 2020-11 look to be obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

You can use django-pyodbc-azure because it has support up to current versions of django 2.0.
After installation you need to edit in your settings file like below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': USER,
        'PASSWORD': PASSWORD,
        'HOST': HOST,
        'PORT': PORT,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
            'unicode_results': True,

        },
    }
}
```

If you install TDS library as driver then your driver will be 'driver':'Free TDS'
Here 13 is the default version. If your installed version is different from that then use that version number instead of 13

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/mssql-django-samples/mssql-django-samples/). First you need to install **mssql-django** package and database configuration should be like

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "mssql",
        "NAME": "Todo",
        "USER": "",
        "PASSWORD": "",
        "HOST": "127.0.0.1",
        "PORT": "1433",
        "OPTIONS": {"driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                    },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `pyodbc`, `django-mssql-backend` modules and set `sql_server.pyodbc` engine settings.